# StoredProcedureItemReader Spring Batch setting param values

Tags: prepared-statement, spring-batch

I am using StoredProcedureItemReader in Spring Batch for Reading Items from a DB via Stored Procedure (Which accepts input parameters).
I have done setting the basic configurations for StoredProcedureItemReader but Not getting how to set the parameters values in it.

```
    StoredProcedureItemReader storedProcItemReader = new StoredProcedureItemReader();
    storedProcItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    storedProcItemReader.setProcedureName("proc_name");

    SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlParameter(OracleTypes.VARCHAR),new SqlParameter(OracleTypes.VARCHAR),new SqlParameter(OracleTypes.CURSOR)};
    storedProcItemReader.setParameters(parameter);
    storedProcItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(??)
```

I want to set the values for two input parameters via PreparedStatementSetter. How do i set it. Do i need to use a preparedstatement for it. As i have already given the proc name (which has all the query to execute).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [ItemPreparedStatementSetter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/ItemPreparedStatementSetter.html) :

```
public class MyItemPreparedStatementSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<T> {

    @Override
    public void setValues(T item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

        //Set your values here, example :
        ps.setString(1, item.getProperty());
    }
}
```

Statement fields are 1-indexed.

Then you can pass it to your reader :

```
  storedProcItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new MyItemPreparedStatementSetter());
```

Comment: Yes did it the same way and its working. Was just concerned about "PreparedStatement ps" in setValues function, as what PreparedStatement  it has to use (do i need to provide or not). But it takes care internally.